# How to use 'Nuitka' to create a CLI app using a library like 'click'

Tags: python, executable, python-click, nuitka

When creating Click CLI apps we need to define entry points, which we do in `setup.py`

For example: (from [click docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/setuptools/))

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='yourscript',
    version='0.1.0',
    py_modules=['yourscript'],
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'yourscript = yourscript:cli',
        ],
    },
)
```

How do we define entry points for nuitka generated executable file.

Answer (score 1):

One way to pass the entry point to nuitka would be as follows:

- Install package in editable mode to generate entry point script
- Pass entry point script to nuitka as the main module

```
$ pip install -e .  
$ python -m nuitka --onefile $(which yourscript)
```